# extra white space top of keyboard in iOS 7

Tags: ios7

I am working on phonegap, when I show keyboard its shows extra white space just above the keyboard.
Please help to find solution.
I cant see whats exact above keyboard, because its hedden below white space. And I am not adding any thing which handles keyboard size.

Comment: Can we have codes ? which version of PhoneCap / Cordova are you using?

Comment: Platform: ios 3.0.0-0-ge670de9... Its cordova

Comment: If you can't share code, you shouldn't ask too. Just few lines of codes won't breach NDA, as long as it does not key logics.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. guessing it has to do with iOS 7's handling of dismissing and pushing things on screen. ill let you know if i find anything

Comment: I solved this issue setting height= device height and same for width in html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added one line in meta tag of html page where I was getting this error. In that line I added the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, user-scalable=no" />
```

and it started working.